# Problem Installing ubuntu via usb in ASUS R510C

Tags: usb, 14.04, asus, bootloader, bios

My boot loader doesn't recognize the usb for booting and installing ubuntu.

I already disabled the secure boot and it still does not recognize the usb.

If there is anyone that has encountered the same problem and knows how to solve it please show me the light.

Comment: You need to verify that the partition is bootable. How did you create the USB stick? If you have another linux machine running, try to reformat the usb stick using `gparted` or a similar tool, and ensure that the boot flag is checked on the partion.

Comment: it is bootable i already use the same usb to install it in my old laptop and it worked fine

Comment: What is the error message displayed? Is it `MBR FA`?

Comment: no error msg, it joust that the boot loader doesn't show/recognize the usb

Comment: "go to Boot in BIOS and enable the option Laucnh CSM and sub option Launch PXE OpROM." from http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/324872-30-boot-bios-asus-x501a

Maybe that could work? Holding Esc during boot has also been described as a solution

Answer (score 0):

"go to Boot in BIOS and enable the option Laucnh CSM and sub option Launch PXE OpROM."

from http://tomshardware.co.uk/forum/324872-30-boot-bios-asus-x501a